# How to solve this recurrence using masters method?

Tags: recurrence, master-theorem

T(n)=4t(n/2) + n^2 and t(1)=1

I dont know guys, I can solve other ones but I seem to get stuck and cant start with this one

Comment: Isn't this more related to programmers, computer science or math stack site?

Answer (score 0):

Let's work through this one and see what we find. In this case, we have a = 4, b = 2, and d = 2. Since log<sub>b</sub> a = 2 = d, we should get that t(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup> log n).

Let's quickly check to see if that's the case by thinking about how much work is done per level in the tree. At the top level, we do n<sup>2</sup> work and then make four calls on problems of size n/2. Each of those problems does (n/2)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup> / 4 work, and since there's four copies of that problem the work done at the next level is n<sup>2</sup>. Each of those subproblems fires off four recursive calls on problems of size (n/4)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup> / 16, and since there are sixteen of those subproblems the work done at that level is also n<sup>2</sup>. Overall, we see that each layer in the tree does n<sup>2</sup> work and that there are Θ(log n) layers, so the total work done is Θ(n<sup>2</sup> log n), matching our bound from the Master Theorem.